# WINPE MDT 2012 Boot Image issues [BootImage Needs To Be Updated VersionUpdate=True]

Tags: sccm

All,

I am attempting to deploy / use a WINPE.WIM in our SCCM infrastructure (2012) and after I updated the distribution points I look at the SMSPXE log and it states:

BootImage PSI000C7 needs to be updated (new packageID=PSI000C7) VersionUpdate=true

I have tried to rip out all DPs out of the BootImage, tried to toggle the "Deploy this boot image from the PXE-enabled distribution point", restarted WDS service, and "redeployed" the task sequence to the target collection.

Unfortunately none of the things I have tried has worked.

Anyone else have any experience with this, if so, how do I force it to update the WIM?

Thanks,
Raged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some more testing, the message in the SMSPXE.LOG:

"BootImage PSI000C7 needs to be updated (new packageID=PSI000C7) VersionUpdate=true"

Appears to be **very** misleading.

I changed a couple of properties (in this case I changed the custom background image) in the Properties of the BootImage:

[image]

It then told me that it needed to update the distribution points, it brought up the wizard recompiled the boot image and I was then set to go.

Thanks everyone.